# How to hide the URl query string?

Tags: query-string, moodle

We have installed Moodle v3.4 (PHP & MySQL) and it is running smoothly. However, and for the sake of security, we need to hide the query string of the URL in all pages.

What is the best way to hide the query string?

Comment: Use `POST` instead.

Comment: `GET` will always need something in the url, like a querystring or a route parameter.

Comment: So what is your advise to do masking of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about Friendly URL. Maybe the below links will help you.

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-28030

https://www.moodleworld.com/add-clean-urls-to-your-moodle-site-using-this-clean-urls-plugin-brendanheywood-moodle-moodledev/

From the above-mentioned plugin, your URL will be converted as below.

Messy URL: http://example.com/course/view.php?id=1

Clean URL: http://example.com/course/1